# How can in create a Start/Stop condition within an subset?

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R so I'd like to apollogize in advance for eventually not choosing the best words to explain my issue.

My problem is that I'd like to create a subset out of a dataset (old) which has several colums. So far no problem...

My subset should start when the value (x) in one of the colums reaches its highest point; and stop right after x droppend down again to its lowest point.
Then create a new dataset (new) with this subset of the data (old).

As there are multiple positions in my original dataset (old) where the value x behaves as descibed above I'd like to have a new dataset (new1, new2, new....) for every subset I create.

I hope a was clear in what I'd like to say. If there is more information needed, I'm happy to provide it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sample data are always helpful (to concretely show input and desired output, and to make it easier for someone to tinker and help you find a solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for instance you have

```
x <- c(5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,2,1)
```

Then

```
direction <- sign(diff(x))
```

will give a series of +1s and -1s indicating whether x is on an upward or downward swing.  We're only interested in downward swings, so let's label upward points with NA, and downward points in the nth swing with the number n:

```
run <- rle(direction)
run$values[run$values==1] <- NA
run$values[!is.na(run$values)] <- 1:sum(!is.na(run$values))
```

Now it seems you want to include the last point in a run of downward points (where the sign is positive, as the point after the last point in a downward run is higher).  So we need to extend the length of downward runs, and decrease the upward:

```
run$lengths <- run$lengths + ifelse(is.na(run$values), -1, +1)
swing <- inverse.rle(run)
plot(x, col=swing)
```

should colour downward runs in different colours, and omit upward runs.  You've now got a variable that labels the runs, and you can split your data.frame by

```
split(myDataFrame, swing)
```

You might need to check this works if we start/finish `a` on an up or down swing

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option where we check when direction changes with `diff`, and then split along that.  First, make some data:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1:3, 2:1), 3))
```

Then:

```
dir.vec <- c(diff(df$x) <= 0, tail(diff(df$x) <= 0, 1)) # has drop started?
split.vec <- cumsum(c(0, diff(dir.vec)) < 0)            # which drop # is this?
split(df[dir.vec,,drop=F], split.vec[dir.vec])          # split drops by drop num
```

Original:

```
   x
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  2
5  1
6  1
7  2
8  3
9  2
10 1
11 1
12 2
13 3
14 2
15 1
```

Split:

```
$`0`
  x
3 3
4 2
5 1

$`1`
   x
8  3
9  2
10 1

$`2`
   x
13 3
14 2
15 1
```